# teamcity prompts for credentials on remote machines

Tags: configuration, teamcity

I'm installing teamcity on a windows server 2008 box running iis7.  I'm using the windows installer supplied by jetbrains.  I've configured the servers to run under a domain account which has been given full control of the build & config directories.  The services are configured to use unused ports (tomcat 14142 & build agent: 9090).  whenever I connect to the tomcat instance from a machine other than the server I am prompted for credentials.  None of the credentials I would expect work.  How can I make this prompt for credentials go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by changing the port number.